# Epplus Export Error like this : 'System.Data.DataSet' the object type 'System.Data.DataTable' not taken in kind.

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export-to-excel, epplus-4

I wanna convert a gridview to .xls but it throws error and when I click ok its give me " Failed to export to excel. Original error: 'System.Data.DataSet'
the object type 'System.Data.DataTable' not taken in kind. " Here is my code;

My search button

```
        groupBox2.Visible = true;
        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=database; Trusted_Connection=yes; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        baglanti.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM hostes_tablo WHERE ayak_no=" + comboBox7.Text + "";

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cmd.Connection = baglanti;
        da.Fill(ds, "hostes_tablo");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "hostes_tablo";
        baglanti.Close();
```

My Export button

```
var saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }

                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource), true);
                    ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

                    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataGridView1.Columns.Count])
                    {
                        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));
                        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                    }

                    pck.Save();
                    pck.Dispose();

                }

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Excel file \"{0}\" generated successfully.", file.Name));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to export to Excel. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

i search then when am i click export button its give me error.

Comment: In which line you are getting the error and can you please post the complete exception details.

Comment: not line. İt's give me while program is running. [Click to see error](http://i.hizliresim.com/z4MkVD.png) @Venky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the casting from `DataSet` to `DataTable` is giving the error. You cannot cast `DataSet` to `DataTable` directly.

Use the code below to do that.

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource; 
DataTable dt= (DataTable) bs.DataSource;

 ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
```

Comment: simular mistake ;
'System.Data.DataSet' the object type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' not taken in kind.

Comment: You should put a `breakpoint` somewhere in the button click event and start debugging line by line then you will know on which line the exception is occuring and it gives you more detailed exception message. This is the only way you can find solution.

Answer (score 2):

you right i was casting from DataSet to DataTable

```
 var saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Dosyası (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataSet;
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["hostes_tablo"];

                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                    if (file.Exists)
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }

                    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("AjansRed Sorgu Sonuç");
                        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);
                        ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                        ws.Cells[1,dataGridView1.Columns.Count+2].Value = label81.Text.ToString();
                        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1])//ws.cells[from row, from column, to row, to column]. sayıların anlamı
                        {
                            rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));
                            rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                        }

                        pck.Save();
                        pck.Dispose();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(@"Sorgu Sonucunuzu İçeren  ""{0}"" Başarıyla Dışarıya Aktarıldı!", file.Name));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hata! Hata! Hata! Excel Dışarı Aktarma Esnasında Sorun Oluştu. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```